# TabLayout text gravity to start

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I am searching for the solution to show tab layout texts as start (just for 2 tabs).
What I want to achieve :

[image]

What I currently have :

[image]

My XML code as follows :

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceTab"/>
```

Comment: did you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this...

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin15dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/fontBlue"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/fontBlue"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextStyle"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/fontPrimary100">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

happy Coding :)

Comment: Yes it is, what you want... Actually, plz elaborate what you want?

Comment: Okay so I have 2 tabs, I want my tab text starts from left and my 2nd tab text starts from center of screen. The solution you shared allow my 2nd tab to starts just after the 1st tab.